# Parsing XML file to get the folder structure?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

From my XML file, I have to retrieve the folder structure.

My folder structure:

[image]

The XML file ( that captures the above folder structure) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<serverfiles name="Test">
  <serverfiles name="Fail">
    <serverfiles name="Cam1">
      <serverfiles name="Mod1">
        <serverfiles name="2019-03-07" />
        <serverfiles name="2019-03-08" />
      </serverfiles>
      <serverfiles name="Mod2">
        <serverfiles name="2019-03-07" />
        <serverfiles name="2019-03-08" />
      </serverfiles>
    </serverfiles>
  </serverfiles>
  <serverfiles name="Pass">
    <serverfiles name="Cam1">
      <serverfiles name="Mod1">
        <serverfiles name="2019-03-07" />
        <serverfiles name="2019-03-08" />
      </serverfiles>
      <serverfiles name="Mod2">
        <serverfiles name="2019-03-07" />
        <serverfiles name="2019-03-08" />
      </serverfiles>
    </serverfiles>
  </serverfiles>
</serverfiles>
```

My Python script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
path_file = ET.parse(r'../../folder_structure.xml')
r = path_file.getroot()
l = [i.attrib for i in r.iter() if i.tag=='serverfiles']
print(l)
```

Above code yields the following result:

> [{'name': 'Test'}, {'name': 'Fail'}, {'name': 'Cam1'}, {'name':
>   'Mod1'}, {'name': '2019-03-07'}, {'name': '2019-03-08'}, {'name':
>   'Mod2'}, {'name': '2019-03-07'}, {'name': '2019-03-08'}, {'name':
>   'Pass'}, {'name': 'Cam1'}, {'name': 'Mod1'}, {'name': '2019-03-07'},
>   {'name': '2019-03-08'}, {'name': 'Mod2'}, {'name': '2019-03-07'},
>   {'name': '2019-03-08'}]

Here, the problem is that, that the entire folder structure is lost ( *Parent-child relationship* is lost). How do I modify my script, so that I can render my list as folder structure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using recursion:

```
from pprint import pprint
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def walk(e):
    name = e.attrib['name']
    children = [walk(c) for c in e if e.tag == 'serverfiles']
    struct = {'name': name}
    if children:
        struct['children'] = children
    return struct

path_file = ET.parse(r'folder_structure.xml')
r = path_file.getroot()
s = walk(r)
pprint(s)
```

And the output:

```
{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'name': '2019-03-07'},
                                                        {'name': '2019-03-08'}],
                                           'name': 'Mod1'},
                                          {'children': [{'name': '2019-03-07'},
                                                        {'name': '2019-03-08'}],
                                           'name': 'Mod2'}],
                             'name': 'Cam1'}],
               'name': 'Fail'},
              {'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'name': '2019-03-07'},
                                                        {'name': '2019-03-08'}],
                                           'name': 'Mod1'},
                                          {'children': [{'name': '2019-03-07'},
                                                        {'name': '2019-03-08'}],
                                           'name': 'Mod2'}],
                             'name': 'Cam1'}],
               'name': 'Pass'}],
 'name': 'Test'}
```

**EDIT:** Updated code to simplify the output (based on the comment):

```
from pprint import pprint
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def walk(e):
    name = e.attrib['name']
    children = [walk(c) for c in e if e.tag == 'serverfiles']
    return {name: children} if children else name

path_file = ET.parse(r'folder_structure.xml')
r = path_file.getroot()
s = walk(r)
pprint(s)
```

The output:

```
{'Test': [{'Fail': [{'Cam1': [{'Mod1': ['2019-03-07', '2019-03-08']},
                              {'Mod2': ['2019-03-07', '2019-03-08']}]}]},
          {'Pass': [{'Cam1': [{'Mod1': ['2019-03-07', '2019-03-08']},
                              {'Mod2': ['2019-03-07', '2019-03-08']}]}]}]}
```

The structure is simpler, but now you have to account for two possible types -- `dict` when the folder has subfolders and `str` if it's a leaf node (no subfolders).

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using 'children' tag ?

Comment: What do you mean by _`children` tag_? You mean `children` _key_? You can adapt the code to suit your needs. If you specify what the structure should be like, I might try to edit the answer.

Comment: Yup!! I was referring to the 'children' key. I think I can adapt the code to suit my requirements

Comment: @Virat Check out the edited answer. Let's hope it suits your needs better.